# Docker login failed in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, acr

I have below piece of code written in Groovy language in Jenkins pipeline. I just want to do docker login but its failing.

`

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build Agent Image') {
            steps {
                dir('jenkins') {
                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'acr-credential', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
                        sh "sudo usermod -aG docker $USER"
                        sh "sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock"
                        sh "docker login --username ${USERNAME} --password ${PASSWORD} example.azurecr.io/test"
                        sh "./build image1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

I am getting below error. Please help me what is the USER, as per docker the first time it should add the user to the Docker group, the same I am doing but still Jenkins unable to identify it.
Help me with the solution.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: USER for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:251)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:9)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor333.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Your pipeline is actually failing because you are attempting to resolve an undefined variable `$USER`. It is unrelated to the registry authentication. You need to define that variable before using it.

Comment: $USER is a root user over here. It needs to be added to the docker group.